# getting the count of a query set in Django

Tags: python, django, api, rest

i am making a doctor appointment system, and i want to get the count of how many appointment i have in a specific day, so instead of doing it this way:

```
appointments_count = Appointment.objects.filter(user = user, date = specific_date).count()
```

will it be more efficient if i make another table for keeping track of the count of the appointments for each date, to avoid more i/o disk operations

```
class Date_Counter(models.Model):
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

and thanks everyone

Comment: The second approach is more decentralized. Use it if you have to query the `Date_Counter` model too.

Comment: yeah i need i will need to query the Date_Counter model to get the count of appointment for each day, so i think it will be much better,

Comment: @RedWheelbarrow have right (if you always need to update `Date_Counter` class. Then choose the first option.

Comment: @Rvector thank you, i thought it will be much faster, so thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never hard code fields that can be obtained with a query (this is a fundamental rule of relational databases). If you use the second approach, you need to always update the count, so the performance is also worst.

Comment: i know, but i wanted to avoid, if i have like 50 appointment per day, and just query all the appointments to just get the count, but i think my approach is bad, so thanks for the advice, thank you so much

Comment: @th3plus You don' t have to query all the appointments, make a query only when you want to know how many appointments a user has. If you want to know how many appointments each user has, you can use a dynamic property in your model (not a field) or annotate the number of appointments for each user in the queryset. Even if you make a query for each appointment, 50 query is not much for a database.

Comment: what i meant is i am going to make a query for the appointment of each date many times, but i know now my approach is worse, thanks @RedWheelbarrow, I really appreciate your help everyone